# GUI gone after apt-get upgrade on clean install, Ubuntu Wily-

Tags: command-line, boot, xorg, upgrade, gui

I was pointed here from AskUbuntu because my question was about an unsupported Ubuntu derivate, here is the copy-pasted question:

> I am aware i am asking a duplicate question, but since the questions([q-1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/718846/no-gui-after-ubuntu-15-04-upgrade),[q-2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/531566/after-upgrade-no-gui)) are **unanswered** i am still going to ask it. **Please, do not flag as duplicate as this implies that no answers are needed, thus leaving yet another question unaswered.**

I upgraded my fresh install of Netrunner 17 Horizon (Ubuntu-based, screenfetch reports that the OS is Wily), and after the reboot i got no GUI except the splash-screen. Removing the `quiet` bootflag shows `Starting version 225` after the splash-screen vanishes, this message does not disappear and there is no further output.

I had this problem a day ago, so i did a clean reinstall and this time i copied the terminal output of the upgrade:

> The terminal output of `apt-get upgrade` exceeded the new question character limit (30.000) at least 4 times, so i dropped the output in here > [pastebin/Jybu3aQB](http://pastebin.com/Jybu3aQB)

**Upgraded packages:**

```
about-distro
bind9-host
binutils
chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra
cups-browsed
cups-filters
cups-filters-core-drivers
curl
dkms
dnsutils
dpkg
dpkg-dev
ffmpeg
firefox
firefox-locale-en
firefox-plasma
flashplugin-installer
grub-common
grub-efi-amd64
grub-efi-amd64-bin
grub-efi-amd64-signed
grub2-common
gtk2-engines-qtcurve
initscripts
isc-dhcp-client
isc-dhcp-common
kate5-data
kde-config-gtk-style-preview
kde-l10n-engb
kde-style-oxygen-qt4
kde-style-qtcurve-qt4
kdelibs-bin
kdelibs5-data
kdelibs5-plugins
kdoctools
kio
kpackagelauncherqml
ksnapshot
ksshaskpass
ktexteditor-katepart
kwin
kwrited
libav-tools-links
libavcodec-extra
libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56
libavdevice-ffmpeg56
libavfilter-ffmpeg5
libavformat-ffmpeg56
libavresample-ffmpeg2
libavutil-ffmpeg54
libbind9-90
libcupsfilters1
libcurl3
libcurl3-gnutls
libdlrestrictions1
libdns-export100
libdns100
libdpkg-perl
libepoxy0
libfontembed1
libirs-export91
libisc-export95
libisc95
libisccc90
libisccfg-export90
libisccfg90
libkcmutils4
libkde3support4
libkdeclarative5
libkdecore5
libkdesu5
libkdeui5
libkdewebkit5
libkdnssd4
libkemoticons4
libkf5iconthemes-bin
libkf5js5
libkf5notifyconfig-data
libkf5notifyconfig5
libkf5parts-plugins
libkf5plotting5
libkf5pty-data
libkf5pty5
libkf5service-bin
libkf5texteditor5-libjs-underscore
libkf5unitconversion-data
libkf5unitconversion5
libkfile4
libkhtml5
libkidletime4
libkio5
libkjsapi4
libkjsembed4
libkmediaplayer4
libknewstuff2-4
libknewstuff3-4
libknotifyconfig4
libkntlm4
libkparts4
libkprintutils4
libkpty4
libkrosscore4
libkrossui4
libktexteditor4
libldb1
liblwres90
libmysqlclient18
libmysqlclient18:i386
libnm-glib-vpn1
libnm-glib4
libnm-util2
libnm0
libnss3
libnss3-nssdb
liboxygenstyle5-5
liboxygenstyleconfig5-5
libperl5.20
libplasma3
libpng12-0
libpng12-0:i386
libpolkit-agent-1-0
libpolkit-backend-1-0
libpolkit-gobject-1-0
libpostproc-ffmpeg53
libpowerdevilui5
libqt5clucene5
libqt5concurrent5
libqt5x11extras5
libqtcurve-utils2
libsmbclient
libsndfile1
libsndfile1:i386
libsolid4
libswresample-ffmpeg1
libswscale-ffmpeg3
libthreadweaver4
libvlc5
libvlccore8
libwbclient0
libxml2
libxml2:i386
libxml2-utils
linux-firmware
linux-libc-dev
mysql-client-core-5.6
mysql-common
mysql-server-core-5.6
nano
netrunner-artwork
netrunner-default-settings
netrunner-desktop-containment
network-manager
openssh-client
openssl
oxideqt-codecs-extra
oxygen-sounds
perl
perl-base
perl-modules
policykit-1
python-apt
python-apt-common
python-ldb
python-libxml2
python-samba
python3-apt
python3-dbus.mainloop.pyqt5
qml-module-org-kde-extensionplugin
qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects
qtcurve
qtcurve-l10n
qtdeclarative5-kf5declarative
qtdeclarative5-kf5solid
rootactions-servicemenu
rsync
samba
samba-common
samba-common-bin
samba-dsdb-modules
samba-libs
samba-vfs-modules
sddm-theme-breeze
smbclient
sysv-rc
sysvinit-utils
thunderbird
thunderbird-locale-en
thunderbird-locale-en-us
thunderbird-plasma
unattended-upgrades
virtualbox
virtualbox-dkms
virtualbox-guest-dkms
virtualbox-guest-utils
virtualbox-guest-x11
virtualbox-qt
vlc
vlc-data
vlc-nox
vlc-plugin-notify
vlc-plugin-pulse
vlc-plugin-samba
wine
xserver-common
xserver-xorg-core
```

I basically have no idea what has gone wrong, google and a search on [SE](https://stackexchange.com) did not reveal anything that i found applicable to my OS, versions, and situation.

I am experiencing every symptom of this [unanswered question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/531566/after-upgrade-no-gui) except the screen going black, for me the trouble began after the reboot.

I would really appreciate any kind of help, hint, or answer.

Comment: Uhm what GUI are we talking about? (KDE? GNOME? Other?) Does X give you errors when you try to launch it (xorg.log?). Is your GUI properly installed, is your xinitrc (or comparable file) properly configured? Can you start the GUI from the console when it fails to launch on boot (**startx**)?

Otherwise, I do notice that X11 is among the upgraded packages, this could very likely be related. What graphics drivers are you using? If catalyst, that could be related as well (that stack is known for being behind Xorg developments)

Comment: @Cestarian i'm sorry i haven't responded, i asked this last night late. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Run through these basics, it's unclear what you mean by 'gui'.

When you boot, you see grub, I assume. You hit enter, and the boot process starts.

When you say 'splash screen', do you mean what you see right after you start the boot from grub process?

Does the disk chatter for a while?

**Guess 1**

This is unlikely, but because it's what most people with this issue would be googling for, I'll list it first.

Let's assume you are actually managing to start the system, and the desktop/video driver is simply not starting.

In that case: what video card does the system use? what video driver does it use?

If nvidia, does it use nvidia non free? If amd, does it use FGLRX? If either, that's why the desktop usually hasn't started, unless you are using distro provided kernels and video drivers, though not all cards are supported on new kernels.

What desktop is it? kde, gnome, etc? What display manager do you use? sddm, lightdm, gdm3, mdm, and so on? If KDE 5.x, then failure is frequent in my experience, my solution is to switch to xfce4 and give up because qt/kde 5 are just broken. Though it sounds like you're not getting to that at all.

If the system has actually started, and no x is showing, then you should be able to hit: ctrl + alt + F1. then you'd get the login for shell. Can you do that?

Before this happened, did you get to a login screen to start your desktop, or did your desktop just start directly?

You need to provide details when you post questions or else everyone is guessing.

**Guess 2**

If you cannot do that, it's likely that systemd itself has failed, that would be my top guess.

To diagnose that requires turning off whatever those boot splash things are called, I can't remember, that fake graphic you see during the boot, starts after grub, and ends right before your dm starts up, and shows the login screen. I think you've done that, judging from the console message you see.

How long does the system hard drive indicator flicker before you get to this point?

```
Starting version 225
```

Almost certainly is referring to systemd failing to start, because Wily probably has systemd release 225, that sounds about right.

If systemd is failing to start, in a sense, I'd say you're #@@#ed. I can barely fix serious systemd breaks when I have direct access to the machine, and can engage all the possible fixes and hacks and guesses that such breaks require. No way I could diagnose a failed derived version (your distro) of a derived distro (ubuntu), that's why askubuntu told you to come here, but really the only place you can actually go is the distro forums or IRC channel. And I doubt they can help you to be honest.

If it's a derived ubuntu, it's possible that someone who created the distro messed up something in the systemd configurations that breaks on a systemd update. If so, good luck, I'd just give up personally at that point if I were you and install regular wily, then install the desktop you want, and go from there.

Note that if you see almost no hard disk activity after hitting grub and starting to boot the os, and you see that message almost immediately, it's very unlikely you or anyone can fix the issue. That's systemd when it breaks, no fun there at all. If on the other hand you see that further into the boot process, which you shouldn't, that's something else, and you may be able to fix it.

Comment: I resolved it by finding out what i can upgrade apart from the regular list, upgrading `sddm` fixed everything for me.

Comment: If sddm fixed it, then it's  not quite what you described. It's useful to learn to post actually relevant information when you say: my gui doesn't start. Anyway, you're lucky if sddm is all it was. I find sddm very unreliable, and won't use it.

Comment: I have no complaints about it except this upgrade trouble. My distro has sddm as default DE, maybe i'll change it whenever i need to.

Answer (score 0):

This might be too case-specific.

I resolved it by manually upgrading my window manager, `sddm`.

```
sudo apt-get install sddm
```

It now works for me.